# Efficient way to loop through 2D hash in perl

Tags: perl, optimization, hash

I am looking for a way to speed up my perl execution.
I have a script that reads a file and creates a 2D hash(with minimum 8million key value pairs). Then I create two separate hashes which contains first level and second level keys for the 2D hash based on user input. But when I try to combine all these to print out the data, the execution is terribly slow.
Here is the block of code to print data (the most time consuming part of the script):

```
open(my $FH_DATA, ">", $report_graph) or die "Cannot open file $!"; 
print $FH_DATA "$HEADER_GRAPH\n";
  foreach my $first_key ( keys %first_level_hash) {
    foreach my $second_key (keys %second_level_hash ) {
      foreach my $rail (@FILTER_BY_RAILS) {
        if( exists $FILTER_BY_RAIL_COMMON{"$first_key.$second_key.$rail"} ) {
          print $FH_DATA " $_ " for @{ $my_2D_hash{$first_key}{$second_key} };
          print $FH_DATA "$rail $second_key $first_key";
          print $FH_DATA "\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
close($FH_DATA);
print "Finished writing $report_graph\n";
```

This nested foreach loops is really killing my execution time. I have been continuously looking at it and became blindsighted now. Any help is much appreciated.

Output from NYTProfiler:
[image]

Comment: Is the order in the output file important? If not, it would make more sense for the outermost two loops to be placed inside the if statement. (`for my $rail (...) { if (exists(...)) { for my $first_key (...) { for my $second_key (...) { ... }}}}`)

Comment: Just ocurred to me ... are `$cell_key` and `$pin_key` by any chance in fact the hash keys?

Comment: I am sorry for making the huge typo. the $pin_key and $cell_key are infact $first_key and $second key. i will edit the question.

Comment: Have you tries using `each` to iterate over **huge** hash? `while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) { ... }`

Comment: How many keys are in `%FILTER_BY_RAIL_COMMON`?

Comment: same as the others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**   *A major rewrite as a critical detail in the question has been updated*

---

The code dereferences two nested hash keys to prepare what is the same for each `$rail`-filtered entry. Those hash lookups, which involve dereferencing, aren't quite free and add up. As the hash-related parts of prints are the same for each filter-loop prepare them outside

```
foreach my $first_key ( keys %first_level_hash) {
    foreach my $second_key (keys %second_level_hash ) {
        my @line_elems = @{ $my_2D_hash{$first_key}{$second_key} };
        foreach my $rail (
            grep { exists $FILTER_BY_RAIL_COMMON{"$first_key.$second_key.$_"} }
            @FILTER_BY_RAILS)
        {
            print $FH_DATA " $_ " for @line_elems;
            print $FH_DATA "$rail $second_key $first_key";
            print $FH_DATA "\n";
        }
}
```

The `grep` should also be a little more efficient than `if` statements in an explicit loop.

Altogether this surely helps, but if `@FILTER_BY_RAILS` is small then probably not dramatically.

That is about what can be done without being able to rearrange operations. A major improvement would be to do the filtering before, perhaps while hashes are being populated so to create a separate data structure ready to print.  (Then loops can be unraveled somewhat more efficiently as well.)

It's still going to cost some; hashes aren't fast and iterating over large ones takes cycles.

---

A small tweak to also try as possibly faster is in printing itself

```
print $FH_DATA ' '.join('  ', @$line).' ';
```

Comment: at line `my @line_elems = @{ $my_2D_hash{$first_key}{$second_key} };`  I get: `Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at`. The data exists as per previous implementation approach. why is it complaining now?

Comment: @tt_pre  That would mean that there is nothing at `$h{k1}{k2}` ... something about names (of hash and keys)?  The line is copied form your code, just moved out of `@FILTER` loop -- so whatever you actually have, move it out of the loop and it must work?  Unless it's in fact significantly different than shown here and it uses the `$rail` element?  Or perhaps you've made other changes as well?